# Continuous random variables: How to calculate $P(X_1<X_2)$

Tags: probability

Suppose we have two discrete random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$. Then

$P\left (X_1<X_2\right )=\sum_x P\left (X_1<X_2\mid X_2=x\right )P\left (X_2=x\right )$

My first question is: Is is true that $P\left (X_1<X_2\mid X_2=x\right )P\left (X_2=x\right )=P(X_1<x)$?

Now, how would be the way of computing $P(X_1<X_2)$ if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two continuous, not discrete, random variables?

Comment: Informally speaking, just integrate instead of summation!

Comment: Obviously requires you to check everything makes sense.

Comment: If $X_2$ is a continuous random variable, $P(X_2=x)=0$, so if I integrate then I obtain $0$ as an answer. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You require the idea of [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)  to define the integral. You are right that $P(X_2=x)=0$  and so for your first question the equality does not hold even with the integration.

Comment: Suppose that the probability density functions of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $f_{X_1}$ and $f_{X_2}$. Is it true that

$P(X_1<X_2)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}P(X_1<y)f_{X_2}(y)dy$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No to your first question. Let $X_1,X_2$ be independent random variables with $P(X_1=k)=1/2$ for $k=1,2$, and $P(X_2=1)=1/4,P(X_2=2)=3/4$. Then $P(X_1<X_2|X_2=2)=P(X_1<2)=P(X_1=1)=1/2$ (since $X_1,X_2$ independent), and $P(X_2=2)=3/4$. So $P(X_1<X_2|X_2=2)P(X_2=2)=1/2*3/4\neq1/2=P(X_1<2).$

If the random variables are continuous, we define conditional expectation differently. As you note, $P(X=c)=0$ for any $c$ in the domain of $X$ if $X$ is a continuous random variable. Instead of discussing probabilities of points, we discuss probabilities that are defined on particular sets (called measurable sets).